# Should you use aws XRay in all your lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

As the title says, should you include XRay tracing in all of your lambdas, or one's that meet some arbitrary requirements (complexity, integrations, etc)?

Comment: Major use cases are described at FAQ https://aws.amazon.com/xray/faqs/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: @MilanGatyas I appreciate the link, however I've been through the FAQ and it does detail what the service does or doesn't do. But it doesn't cover application patterns. My question is more aimed at what people think of the application pattern of always having xray enabled.

Comment: I'd say if it fits your budget then there is no problem with it. In general I tend to enable it only when traceability becomes hard due to high distribution of the system, otherwise keep it off. It can be enabled later without side effects